# What is the better way to calculate time required for Database call?

Tags: scala, playframework, performance-testing

In my code, from so many places DAO making database calls. I would like to know which is the good way to do this.

I can put logs 1st with a current timestamp before the call and 2nd take the difference of it after the call is complete, But by this way, I have to do the changes all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

You could just introduce code block wrapper, that would measure elapsed time:

```
def measure[R](body: => R): R = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = body
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(s"Task took: ${end - start} ms.") // replace with proper logging
    result
}
```

and then you could just use it like:

```
def doStuff() = measure {
    doJdbcCall();
    val result = doSomethingElse();
    result
}
```

or

```
val result = measure(doJdbcCall)
```

You will still have to modify your code base, but all logic calculating time difference will be hidden under the `measure` method.

As Andrij noticed, it won't work for functions returning any asynchronous effect, like `Future`, but we could prepare overloaded method to handle standards library `Future`:

```
def measure[R](f: Future[R]): Future[R] = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    f.onComplete{
      case _ => 
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println(s"Task took: ${end - start} ms.") // replace with proper logging
    }
    f
}
```

Comment: This won't if `body` launches asynchronous task, e.g. `R = Future[_]`. This will measure only `Future` launch time. E.g. `def measure(db run query.result)`

Comment: what about using aspectj, is yes then how to use it?